# Spark: How to parse key-value pairs in a csv into a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a flat file with multiple columns (showing 2 as an example)

```
column1name=value1|column2name=value2\n
column1name=value3|column2name=value4\n
```

I need to parse it into a standard dataframe

```
|      column1name    |     column2name  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          value1     |         value2   |
|          value3     |         value4   |
```

I have tried reading it into csv, splitting by pipe (which is the separator) and got stuck here. I have some practice with using sparkSQL and DFs, but I've only read about RDDs, never worked on them.

Edit:
I've just checked and sadly, some columns may be missing in my csv. For example:

```
column1name=value1|column2name=value2\n
column1name=value3|column2name=value4\n
column1name=value3|column2name=value4|column3=value5\n
```

I must assume, that not only the last column could go missing, but others too. And what's worrying, the missing column is not represented as null, as it would be in a traditional csv, with nothing between separators - it's just not there.

PS. If possible, I'd be great if I could get away without using sparkcontext, just spark session (*I don't have hdfs connection configured and for some reason when I do spark.read i get a nice dataframe, but when try sc.textFile I keep getting kerberos and hadoop errors*)

Comment: Will you always have `column1name=` in the first column or is it possible that you have `column2name=` in that column? This makes a difference, because in the former case you don't have to parse the column names and in the latter you do.

Comment: Unfortunately i've just checked and a column might be missing, i.e. we could have column1name = value1, column3name = value2. @Koedlt

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question and edit the part where you specify what your input file looks like to include some of those edge cases? Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you. I've just added an example @Koedlt

Comment: it might be easier for you if you read it using basic python and pandas, parse it as per the needs and then convert to spark dataframe

Comment: @PipelineSurfer You can parse the dataset using pandas relatively easily than Pyspark by providing the names of the columns exclusively to handle the issue of missing columns. Add the pandas tag if you are willing to accept the pandas-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

# specify the path to your CSV file
filepath = "/path/to/your/csv/file"

# read the CSV as a text file
raw = spark.read.text(filepath)

# split the data by '|'
split_col = split(raw['value'], '\\|')

# create a DataFrame from the parsed data
data = raw.select(split(split_col.getItem(0), '=').alias('column1name'),
                  split(split_col.getItem(1), '=').alias('column2name'))

# select the columns and values
df = data.select(data.column1name.getItem(1).cast('double').alias('column1name'),
                 data.column2name.getItem(1).cast('double').alias('column2name'))

df.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how we deal with varying column number here. Am I correct to understand this solution works only if you know how many columns you have? @aravind-yarram

Answer (score 0):

We can use pandas as follows to get the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

# Put all the column names into a list
column_names = ["column1name", "column2name", "column3name"]

# Read the flat file as a CSV using pandas with pipe character as the separator
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_flatfile.txt', sep = "|", names = column_names)

# Split over equals sign and take the second element if it is of type string
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('=')[1] if isinstance(x, str) else None)

# Remove the "\n" character
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[:-2] if x is not None and "\\n" in x else x)

df
```

Output:

| column1name | column2name | column3name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | None |
| value3 | value4 | None |
| value3 | value4 | value5 |

Note: Here, you need to check the flat file first for the row with the maximum number of columns and put the names into the column_names list.